# Example of a convergent series of random variables with infinite variance

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

While working through Chapter 3, Section 7 of Cinlar's Probability and Stochastics, I encountered the following proposition.

"Suppose that ($X_n$) is a bounded sequence of independent variables. If $\sum(X_n - a_n)$ is almost surely convergent for some sequence $(a_n)$ in R, then $\sum var(X_n) \leq \infty$."

Because the statement includes boundness as a criteria, there seemingly exists a convergent (and unbounded) series with infinite variance. Though I have tried to construct such series, I have struggled with proving that the series indeed converge.

I have tried modifying the approach used in the proof of the converse of the statement (suppose $(X_n)$ are indp.: then if $\sum var(X_n)$ cvg, $\sum X_n$ cvg almost surely). In particular, the proof uses Kolmogorov's inequality, and I tried to prove a similar inequality in terms of $E[S_n^3]$, hoping that a series with a bounded higher moment could work. However, this approach failed.

How can I incorporate the unboundedness of the random variables?

Comment: You are claiming that in certain conditions, a sum of nonnegative numbers is less than or equal to $\infty$.  But a sum of nonnegative numbers is **always** less than or equal to $\infty$. So the proposition you stated is not useful.  Likely you meant strictly less than $\infty$.

Comment: For your question on removing boundedness, you can define $X_1$ as any random variable with infinite variance and define $X_n=0$ for all $n\geq 2$.